# Terminate program that opens webcam when pressing key

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to build a webcam emotion recognizer using cv2 and FER. The thing is that at some point I want to break out of the `while` loop where I am getting my frames from my webcam and the sentiment analysis takes place. The problem is that when I am pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to break the loop nothing happens. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
import cv2
from fer import FER 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # Open webcam
emotion_detector = FER()

# Check if the webcam is opened correctly
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam") 

while True:

    c = cv2.waitKey(100)
    if c == 27:
        break
    
    ret, frame = cap.read() # Returns a frame and a boolean
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)


    
    print(emotion_detector.detect_emotions(frame))



cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: So, what is actually being returned by `c = cv2.waitKey(100)`?

Comment: @RandomDavis It is -1 constantly, even when I press a key

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7) it seems that `waitKey` returns `-1` if there was no key detected during the delay period. The delay is in milliseconds, meaning you program halts for 100ms every loop iteration and listens for a key during that time. If you increase the time to something like 1000ms or more, does it work then? But it sounds like [pollKey](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga6d20fbd3100ec3badc1eaa653aff99d7) is much closer to what you want, any reason you're not using that instead?

Comment: @RandomDavis I tried both of these solutions and again nothing

Comment: @RandomDavis It's like it doesn't even detects the pressing of the key

Comment: `waitKey` does nothing, not even wait, if you haven't used `imshow` or `namedWindow`. its purpose is to drive OpenCV's GUI facilities. you have no GUI. press `Ctrl+C` to cause a `KeyboardInterrupt` from within python. catch it or don't. -- the docs **note** that waitKey requires at least one window to function. -- it also pays to tag `opencv` because `cv2` is a deprecated tag that's watched by fewer people

Comment: oh and since you're using VideoCapture without any error checking, I suggest that you do that. `assert cap.isOpened()` *once before* the loop,  and in the loop: `if not ret: break`